# Chart of the most frequently occurring words

Tags: c#, charts

There is a code for the 4 most frequently occurring word

```
  string words = "One one Two two three four".ToLower();

  var results = words
    .Split(' ')
    .Where(x => x.Length > 3)
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => new { 
       Count = x.Count(), 
       Word = x.Key })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .Take(3);

 foreach (var item in results)
 {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Join("\n", results.Select(x => String.Format("{0} --- {1} ", x.Word, x.Count)));
 }
```

[image]

How can I make a chart of frequency of words like this

[image]

I know how to make chart, but I don't know how to connect it to my code

```
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("one", 2);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("two", 2);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("three", 1);
this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("four", 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
foreach (var  r in results )
{
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(r.Word, r.Count);
}
```

After changing the data a little:

```
string words = "One one Two two three four four four two two two five five".ToLower();
```

We get this:

[image]

Do note that this is a case of having strings as the x-values. This means that the actual x-values in the DataPoints are not those strings (they are`double`)
but are all `0`.

Which has all sorts of implications.

One is that you can't easily add another series with points that show other values but rely on the same x-values. Nor can you use the (lost) values to set Minimum/Maximum values or format labels..

Sometimes having an additional series with the same x-values, but maybe in a different order, can be made to work by calling [Chart.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd467838(v=vs.110).aspx)..